# Existe justificativa para essa alteração? Mudança no padrão de variáveis

Tags: c#, variáveis, estilo-de-codificação

Um colega de trabalho leu em um fórum que usar short, int e long era o jeito correto e melhor para o desempenho do sistema, então este começou a alterar em todas as telas e classes em que trabalhava.
Eu pesquisei e não vi ganho nenhum, exceto o fato de existir alguma perda de bytes quando se trabalha com conversões de double, mas a questão não é essa, a questão é que está mudando o padrão do sistema que foi feito todo usando tipos Int16,Int32 e Int64, e daí temos agora algumas poucas classes e telas com outro padrão.

A pergunta é: Existe justificativa seja por padrão de desenvolvimento, ganho de sistema, ou ser mais bonito usar assim? Algum motivo que justifique essa despadronização de desenvolvimento que essa "melhoria" está gerando?

Comment: De que linguagem está falando ?

Comment: Sim, é de `C#` (`.NET`)?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira C# .Net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Não existe absolutamente nenhuma diferença entre um e outro, exceto a leitura do código por um humano.

O *alias* figura como uma palavra-chave (*keyword*) da linguagem, mas o uso, função e funcionamento é idêntico a utilizar o seu tipo ou classe equivalente.

*short*, *int*, *long*, *string*... são **apelidos** (*alias*) C# para os seus tipos no .Net Framework (*System.Int16*, *System.Int32*, *System.Int64* e *System.String*, respectivamente) e durante a execução não fará nenhuma diferença se você usou um ou outro para declarar a variável.

Quanto ao seu colega fazer diferente do que vinha sendo feito e alegar que cada um codificará de um jeito, contradiz o senso comum de que o time deve escolher padrões, informal ou formalmente se necessário, e todos devem adotar os padrões.

Quando todo o código segue o mesmo padrão, depois de nos acostumarmos com este padrão ninguém se sente desconfortável ao ler o código alheio e ficamos dispensados de ter que fazer o fatídico "chaveamento" de modo de leitura a cada vez que vamos ler outro código.

> Além dos padrões de estilo que evitam as constantes adaptações por parte do leitor, existem também os padrões pela segurança, robustez, qualidade do código. Se um time não segue nem os padrões de estilo, seguirá outros padrões ainda mais importantes?

Uma evidência da importância de o time seguir um padrão de codificação é a existência de ferramentas especializadas nisso (por exemplo: StyleCop, FxCop e Resharper).

## Afinal, existe justificativa para essa alteração?

A única justificativa plausível é a preferência do seu colega por este estilo que ele está adotando.

Qualquer outra justificativa é falta de informação ou só uma mentirinha mesmo.

Comment: Hoje esse colega não está mais na empresa, com a saída dele hoje após conversar com o resto da equipe fiz um levantamento das classes que ele modificou para que possamos abrir tarefas de adequação aos padrões do projeto.
No total temos que alterar **1229 linhas de código**. :)
Algo que será posto na fila pois não é prioridade, e provavelmente o sistema nunca ficará inteiramente no padrão original.

Obrigado a todos que se deram ao trabalho de responder a esta pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Geralmente, não existe justificativa para contrariar o padrão estabelecido. Se o projeto está usando 100% `int`, `long`,  e `short`, continua utilizando, mesmo com `Int16`, `Int32`, e `Int64`.

Agora, creio que a pior coisa que poderia fazer é deixar o projeto com essa mistura -- fica difícil acompanhar qual padrão deveria estar seguindo.

Se seu colega começou mudar tudo para `int`, acredito eu que teria mudar *tudo*, não deixar nada no outro jeito.

Comment: Concordo, foi o que eu argumentei.
Mas este colega disse: 
"Cara cada um de nós tem um jeito de programar, a gente nunca vai programar do mesmo jeito."

Comment: Sim, cada programador tem um jeito - mas na área de desenvolvimento, é melhor o *time* estabelecer uma padrão, pois o *time* terá que manter o código-fonte. Tem um ditado aqui nos states que descreve um programador que quer fazer tudo diferente simplesmente porque pode: *Cowboy Coder*

Comment: Diante desse comentário: "Cara cada um de nós tem um jeito de programar, a gente nunca vai programar do mesmo jeito." me faz pensar que ele quer mudar pois ele QUER, sem nenhuma outra justificativa aparente e muito menos técnica.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que se ele esteja programando SOZINHO em um projeto poderia fazer da forma que achar melhor, porém como existe uma equipe, deve haver regras e padrões estabelecidas e concordadas com a mesma no inicio do projeto.

Qualquer coisa que esteja fora dos padrões deve ser justificado o motivo de não seguir aquilo que foi combinado, mesmo que seja através de um simples comentário de uma linha.

Concordo que cada um tem uma forma diferente de programar e nem por isso um ou outro estará errado, mas para que em um projeto a melhor forma seja definida (para não acabar virando "miscelânea), deve ser estabelecidos padrões.

Para mudar algum padrão deve ser dada a justificativa do mesmo e logo ser debatido e aceito por todos. Mesmo que isso seja simples e leve em torno de 10 minutos para acontecer, mas é a equipe, e não um ou outro que decide. Ao menos que este tem autoridade para passar por cima dos outros mas mesmo assim penso que não seria a melhor alternativa.

Comment: Concordo, eu até concordei que fosse assim nos sistemas novos, porém como já dito antes em toda tela que ele toca, seja sistema novo ou velho ele faz isso.